Estimating seat occupancy on my flight
I am flying on a Turkish airlines flight TK4751 (also listed as 6E 17) from Mumbai to Istanbul today (8th June).
I was curious what the flight occupancy was (eg to estimate the chance of me getting a middle seat empty or even an upgrade).
On the Indigo airlines seat selection interface, I do see lots of free seats at the moment, but that could also be since online check in is not so easy.
I recall there were indeed websites that allowed one to estimate occupancy of specific flights. Any reccomendations?

You can check Experflyer (with a pro subscription, but there's a 5-day free trial without payment info required) and look at the availabilities for that flight. If it says Y9 there are at least 9 free seats in coach, in theory.

Indigo does not return any availability info. Turkish say 4 seats in coache available (and none in the premium classes), but that might be out of their quota of seats on this flight, so I'm not sure if this can be relied upon.
